# Parallel aggregate multiple doubles

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

How does one parallelise a loop where more than one doubles are aggregated?

It is possible to perform this as two, or more, `Parallel.For` loops where a single double is summed however, in my case, this would necessitate repetition of a costly function common to both variables.

Simplified example in single-threaded form:

```
static void Main()
{
    double sum1 = 0.0;
    double sum2 = 0.0;
    for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
    {
        double result = function1(i);
        sum1 += result;
        sum2 += function2(result);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sum1 + " " + sum2);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static double function1(int x)
{
    return Math.Exp((double)x);
}

private static double function2(double x)
{
    return Math.Pow(x, 2);
}
```

Functions 1 and 2 here are actually very expensive so must only be evaluated once.

The code I found for aggregating one double:

```
        object lockObject = new object();
        double sum = 0.0d;

        Parallel.For(0, 10,
            () => 0.0d,

            (x, loopState, partialResult) =>
            {
               return (double)x / 100.0 + partialResult;
            },

            (localPartialSum) =>
            {
               lock (lockObject)
               {
                 sum += localPartialSum;
               }
            });
```

Comment: Can you give us some code, for example the single-threaded equivalent of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Ok, I have updated the post with a simplified version of what I would like to achieve (the real functions are much too long winded). I can do a single parallel aggregation of ints or doubles, but not multiple variables simultaneously.

Comment: Could you show us what the single parallel aggregation looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Parallel.For` with thread local data:

```
object sync = new object();
double sum1 = 0.0;
double sum2 = 0.0;
Parallel.For<Tuple<double, double>>(2, 10,
    () => { return new Tuple<double, int>(0.0, 0.0); },
    (i, pls, state) =>
    {
        double result = function1(i);
        state = new Tuple<double, double>( state.Item1 + result, state.Item2 + function2(result))
        return state;
    },
    state => { lock (sync) { sum1 += state.Item1; sum2 += state.Item2; } }
);
```

If you use a mutable class containing two `double`s instead of the `Tuple`, you could simplify the code a bit.

Comment: Missing one semicolon, but I won't criticise. Perfect!